# Limit Property Proof

Tags: calculus, limits

I was reading the following article: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitProofs.aspx and I got stuck on **Proof 1**. I think that one can choose a **delta one** because by definition there must be a **delta** for every **epsilon** if a limit exist. What I don't understand is the last part of the proof, when he substitute the **delta one** by **delta** in the last expression I really don't get it. Why is this a proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the proof is short enough, it would be good to post the theorem and the proof here so that your posted question is self-contained. But in any event, it looks like the introduction of $\delta_1$ and then setting $\delta = \delta_1$ was not necessary. If you just say $\delta$ the whole way through the proof and never mention $\delta_1$, the proof still works just fine.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the theorem, I don't know how to do it. Also I don't understand the last part with inequalities, in the last expression why is everything equals to epsilon, I don't get it

Comment: $\delta_1$ was chosen so that the difference quantity there (before multiplying by $c$) was less than $\epsilon / |c|$. So in reality, probably the author should have called $\epsilon_1 = \epsilon / |c|$ if they wanted to introduce $\delta_1$. The point is, once you have $\delta$ that works for that $\epsilon_1$, then since the desired difference quantity is the same as with $\epsilon_1$, but simply multiplied by $|c|$, you get the quantity is less than $|c| \epsilon_1 = \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\delta$ is chosen after $\epsilon$.

Is as if you were in a game.

One person sets the margin of error $\epsilon$, the other tries to reach the value with a smaller error for every value of $x$ within the $\delta$ margin (that you chose after $\epsilon$!)

In the end he only renamed $\delta = \delta_1$ since $\delta_1$ served a strange purpose and $\delta$ suits your goal.